# SSO in Azure B2C using ExternalAD email address with fallback to Internal B2C email address

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have SSO with Azure B2C working fine using in-tenant and email. I would like to add the ability for users to login in with ExternalAzureAd such that if the enter their email address and password it will first use ExternalAzureAd if they have already been invited or if not fallback to the B2C tenant.
I can "see" whether on not a particular email address is Internal or External by viewing the users in B2C Users screen in the portal. I am rather surprised that out of the box the user is not forwarded to the appropriate login screen for authentication - either B2C or External - based on this information.
So I have been told one way to possible implement this is to create an API app that will look this up based on user profile and then based on the info branch to either the Internal or External login screen.
This would involve creating custom policie(s) and perhaps custom user flow(s) so that the API call in ingested into the user flow.

Has anyone done this or know of a reason this would not work?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "ExternalAzureAd", you mean another Azure AD tenant you have federated with?

If so, you can automatically redirect based on the domain name.

Refer to the "Home Realm Discovery" samples [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples?tab=readme-ov-file#user-experience).

Comment: I have 2 aps registered in B2C, they work fine with Local Account.
I BELIEVE I can set them up to use Microsoft Account via User Flow or Custom Policies. 
User Flow:
Registered apps MUST be linked to Microsoft Account by Creating a New OpenID Connect provider.
Custom Polices:
MUST be added per the Sample Code.

As new customers are added
User Flow: More New OpenID Connect provider need to be added.
Custom Polices:
Domains need be added to DomainLookup & more values like
<Item Key="ClaimValueOnWhichToEnable">jsuri.com</Item>
Need to be added perhaps in new section.
Is this correct?

Comment: With user flows, you can't automatically redirect. You just get lots of buttons. With custom policies, yes, you keep adding to DomainLookup, etc.